# Minimum bandwidth limit on Linux systems

Tags: iptables, traffic-shaping, tc, bandwidth-control, network-traffic

I need to limit the minimum bandwith from an IP to specific services/ports, by dropping all the packets that will not satisfy that minimum rate.

I saw the attribute `rate` in the HTB class of the Linux `tc` traffic shaping tool should do this; is it the right tool or other tools are suggested (note that I'm working from a network tap running Linux)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is the right tool.

In fact the traffic shaping is implemented on kernel level. `tc` is the userland interface tool to control it. It is part of the `iproute2` package.

http://lartc.org/ has good documentation
or see also references in [How to do traffic shaping (rate limiting) with TC per OpenVPN client](https://serverfault.com/questions/777875/how-to-do-traffic-shaping-rate-limiting-with-tc-per-openvpn-client/780233#780233)

`rate` in HTB classes is used to set the minimum desired speed to which to limit transmitted traffic.

Meaning the traffic should not be lower than the given `rate` (like a guaranteed rate). It can be higher depending on other parameters like `burst` and the configuration of the parent classes. But it does not drop anything if the actual transmission rate is lower than specified by the given `rate` parameter.