# OpenVPN Traffic Control on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, openvpn, bandwidth, traffic-shaping

I'm trying to give my OpenVPN some bandwidth limitation. I would like for example for each user give 10Mb/s for upload and download. I tried the following answer I found ([Automatically Call a Script when a New User Connects and Bandwidth Shape the Connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/779200/automatically-call-a-script-when-a-new-user-connects-and-bandwidth-shape-the-con)) but it seems like it doesn't change the limitation.

Here is my `server.conf` :

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user openvpn
group nobody
script-security 2
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_3sO9TzCVUQf73j0R.crt
key server_3sO9TzCVUQf73j0R.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
down-pre
up "/usr/bin/sudo /etc/openvpn/tc.sh"
down "/usr/bin/sudo /etc/openvpn/tc.sh"
client-connect "/usr/bin/sudo /etc/openvpn/tc.sh"
client-disconnect "/usr/bin/sudo /etc/openvpn/tc.sh"
```

The script `tc.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >>/tmp/ov.log 2>&1
chmod 666 /tmp/ov.log 2>/dev/null
echo
date
id
echo "PATH=$PATH"
printenv
TC=$(which tc)
interface="eth0"
interface_speed="100mbit"
client_ip="$trusted_ip"
client_ip_vpn="$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip"
download_limit="10mbit"
upload_limit="10mbit"
handle=`echo "$client_ip_vpn" | cut -d. -f4`

function start_tc {
  tc qdisc show dev $interface | grep -q "qdisc pfifo_fast 0"
  [ "$?" -gt "0" ] && tc qdisc del dev $interface root; sleep 1

  $TC qdisc add dev $interface root handle 1: htb default 30
  $TC class add dev $interface parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $interface_speed burst 15k
  $TC class add dev $interface parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate $download_limit burst 15k
  $TC class add dev $interface parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate $upload_limit burst 15k
  $TC qdisc add dev $interface parent 1:10 handle 10: sfq perturb 10
  $TC qdisc add dev $interface parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10
}

function stop_tc {
  tc qdisc show dev $interface | grep -q "qdisc pfifo_fast 0"
  [ "$?" -gt "0" ] && tc qdisc del dev $interface root
}

function filter_add {
  $TC filter add dev $interface protocol ip handle ::${handle} parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip ${1} ${2}/32 flowid 1:${3}
}

function filter_del {
  $TC filter del dev $interface protocol ip handle 800::${handle} parent 1: prio 1 u32
}

function ip_add {
  filter_add "dst" $client_ip_vpn "10"
  filter_add "src" $client_ip_vpn "20"
}

function ip_del {
  filter_del
  filter_del
}

if [ "$script_type" == "up" ]; then
        start_tc
elif [ "$script_type" == "down" ]; then
        stop_tc
elif [ "$script_type" == "client-connect" ]; then
        ip_add
elif [ "$script_type" == "client-disconnect" ]; then
        ip_del
fi
```

The status of TC (`tc -s qdisc ls dev eth0`) :

```
qdisc mq 0: root
 Sent 8177286642 bytes 10438838 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 6271)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 6271
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :4 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 1602437629 bytes 2633658 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 1623)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 1623
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :3 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 1165086682 bytes 1882591 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 990)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 990
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 1060987843 bytes 1677074 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 657)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 657
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :1 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 4348774488 bytes 4245515 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 3001)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 3001
```

Here is a speedtest :
[image: Speed test]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are controlling the traffic in you eth0 interface and not in tun0 interface. The trick using tc is using iptables to mark the traffic and set your QoS policy by user o traffic type.